# Rechart Scrollable bar chart, In a simple bar chart with large data how to implement scroll when Bar is dragged left or right( without Brush or Pan)

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, chart.js, recharts

Hi I want to implement bar chart in rechart react. it should scroll when user clicks and drags Bar to Left or Right. I have already tried Brush and Panning but not suitable for me. requirement is no external slider to be used chart itself should be scrollable on drag

Comment: Please post the code you already have.

Comment: I am not facing any issue with rechart I am just checking for ways to implement scrolling behavior in any chart but without introducing scroller like Brush component, it should be in chart scrolling